# Sharepoint 2013 on premise in ADFS

Tags: sharepoint-2013, saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.0

There is a Sharepoint 2013 installation which uses ADFS for authentication with the internal domain controller. The need is to write a console app/android app which can browse to a folder and then upload a document into sharepoint server. The problem I am facing is how to authenticate because the SAML 2.0 ECP profile which is required for non-browser based SAML authentication is not supported by ADFS. Is there any way in which the application can be written or is it not possible at all.

Answer (score 1):

Check the code sample available here:

[Remote Authentication in SharePoint Online Using the Client Object Model](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Remote-Authentication-in-b7b6f43c)

The idea is to simulate a user browsing Sharepoint to retrieve the FedAuth authentication cookie, and then using this cookie in your app to perform other Sharepoint calls.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But is it possible without installing SharePoint Foundation 2010 client object model redistributable. The implementation language is java and the environment is Linux based.

Comment: Yes it is. Everything is standard based, nothing Sharepoint specific. Just HTTP requests, cookie handling and other similar cross-platform stuff. Basically this method is mimicking a browser.